# Order in which mq_receive calls on an empty POSIX message queue unblock

Tags: linux, posix, ipc, message-queue

When creating a message queue *without* O_NONBLOCK, then `mq_receive()` calls block if the queue is **empty**. When a new message is sent to the queue, which of the waiting `mq_receive()` calls actually unblocks?

The QNX documentation explicitly mentions a FIFO order:

> If multiple `mq_receive()` calls are blocked on a single queue, then
>   they're unblocked in FIFO order as messages arrive. 
>   https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/lib_ref/m/mq_receive.html

Is this the case for all POSIX IPC implementations? What does the Linux implementation do? The man-page is rather unspecific:

> If the queue is empty, then, by default, `mq_receive()` blocks until a
>   message becomes available, or the call is interrupted by a signal
>   handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this in the [POSIX documentation for `mq_receive()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mq_receive.html):

> If more than one thread is waiting to receive a message when a message arrives at an empty queue and the Priority Scheduling option is supported, then the thread of highest priority that has been waiting the longest shall be selected to receive the message. Otherwise, it is unspecified which waiting thread receives the message.

The Linux manpage doesn't mention anything about that priority scheduling rule, but I don't know if that's an omission or because it doesn't implement that feature.